# Intellij function argument formatting

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij when I format arguments it will look like this:

```
    Object.function("String", "String two");
    Object.function("String String", "String two");
    Object.function("String String String ", "String two");
```

However, I would prefer if I could modify the formatter so it will look like this:

```
    Object.function("String",           "String two");
    Object.function("String String",    "String two");
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style: `Object.function("String", "String two")` is controlled by `Editor > Code Style > Java > Spaces > Other > After comma`. This ensures that a space is always added after a ",".

There is **no** option in `Editor > Code Style > Java` to add tabs? fixed space? or whatever this is: `Object.function("String",           "String two")` after a method call argument.

It's not clear to me what your end goal is but if your intention is to **align** method parameters and you are ok with splitting method parameters across lines then the following *might* help.

`Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Method call arguments` then select `Wrap always` and tick `Align when multiline`. 
Here's a screenshot:

[image]

With this configuration, the three method declarations in your question will be reformatted like so:

```
    ObjectA.function("String",
                     "String two");

    ObjectA.function("String String",
                     "String two");

    ObjectA.function("String String String ",
                     "String two");
```